# Why is grep perl-regex mode treating UTF-8 stream/file as binary?

Tags: grep, pcre

I tried to use perl-regex mode, as I wanted to match possible spanned pattern like:

```
...
text text Name
Surname text text
...
```

if I wanted to match "Name Surname".

So using `<stdout> | grep -Pzo "(?s)Name.Surname"` works great for ASCII, but if I want to try the same on utf-8 encoded file I get:

```
Binary file (standard input) matches
```

when I feed grep with it and no results. I also tried with regular file `grep -Pzo "(?s)Name.Surname" utf-8.txt` but it's same

OTOH grep without perl-regex switch works as expected on same stream

So is there any switch, that can solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can tell `grep` to treat it as a text file by using the `-a` or `--binary-files=text` option:

```
... | grep -aPzo "(?s)Name.Surname"

grep -aPzo "(?s)Name.Surname" utf-8.txt
```